# Retrieving CSV from GitHub Repository for later use in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: csv

I am trying to use data from GitHub at this location: https://github.com/factbook/factbook.csv/blob/master/data/c2147.csv

Is there a way to convert this to csv or utilize in some other more interesting way?

In the end, I would like to publish the resulting layer to ArcGIS Online.  I have the country boundary file to join already.

Comment: Although you later want to use this CSV in ArcGIS Online, your question here seems to be about how to retrieve it from Github which has no GIS component.  I think it would have been better researched/asked at the [webapps.se] Stack Exchange which has a tag for [github](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw data from raw.githubusercontent.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/factbook/factbook.csv/master/data/c2147.csv